# How to do both positive lookahead and lookbehind in Bigquery

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery, re2

We want to match two specific characters around another word, for example, to match `-` or `_` around word `ben`,

```
abentest    - not match
bentest     - not match
aben        - not match
a-ben       - match
a_ben       - match
ben-test    - match
a-ben-test  - match
a_ben-test  - match
```

It could be done through positive lookahead and lookbeind like `.*((?<=[_-])(ben)|(ben)(?=[_-])).*`.

However, the lookahead and lookbehind do not support Bigquery regex [re2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax). What is the alternative way to do it in Bigquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could phrase this sans lookarounds by using a regex alternation:

```
.*(?:[_-]ben|ben[_-]).*
```

Here is a working regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/XuPvM2/2).